# Is there any way to update the response of a controller action by pipeline process?

Tags: exm, pipelines, controller, processor

Is there any way that I can update the response of a controller action by pipeline process?

In httpRequestEnd or httpRequestBegin for example

P.S:
I'm using Sitecore 9 update 1 included EXM. I created 2 facets fields to the contact. And now, in the EXM - Email Campaign detail page, I would like to show these facets fields value into the Recipient activity tab. I see that the data for this tab came from the response of `Sitecore.EmailCampaign.Server.Controllers.DataSource.OpensClicksController` (`/sitecore/api/ssc/EXM/OpensClicks`) . So I think if I can catch the response of this request, edit it by adding facets fields value

Many thanks.

Comment: Can you please provide more information on what you want to achieve?

Comment: I'm using Sitecore 9 update 1 included EXM. I created 2 facets fields to the contact. And now, in the EXM - Email Campaign detail page, I would like to show these facets fields value into the Recipient activity tab. I see that the data for this tab came from the response of Sitecore.EmailCampaign.Server.Controllers.DataSource.OpensClicksController (/sitecore/api/ssc/EXM/OpensClicks) . So I think If I can catch the response of this request, edit it by adding facets fields value

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For who needs the answer. We can abort the default request and return a custom response by something like code below. My code in this case is abort the default EXM's OpensClicks request and return a custom result that includes some contact facets fields

Create a new pipeline process and patch it after **Sitecore.Pipelines.HttpRequest.ItemResolver, Sitecore.Kernel**

The process class should be something like that

```
public class ApiRedirectProcessor : HttpRequestProcessor
    {
        public override void Process(HttpRequestArgs args)
        {
                if (args.RequestUrl.AbsolutePath.Contains("/sitecore/api/ssc/EXM/OpensClicks"))
                {
                    try
                    {
                        args.AbortPipeline();
                        var messageid = args.HttpContext.Request.Params["messageId"];
                        var recepientList = GetRecipientList(messageid);
                        if (recepientList != null && recepientList.Any())
                        {
                            var managerRootId = args.HttpContext.Request.Params["managerRootId"];
                            var pageIndex = int.Parse(args.HttpContext.Request.Params["pageIndex"]);
                            var pageSize = int.Parse(args.HttpContext.Request.Params["pageSize"]);
                            var openClickStatisticsService = ServiceLocator.ServiceProvider.GetService<OpenClickStatisticsService>();
                            MessageDataSourceContext data = new MessageDataSourceContext()
                            {
                                MessageId = messageid,
                                ManagerRootId = managerRootId,
                                PageIndex = pageIndex,
                                PageSize = pageSize
                            };

                            Task<RecipientActivityResponse> task = System.Threading.Tasks.Task.Run<RecipientActivityResponse>(async () => await openClickStatisticsService.GetResponse(data));
                            CustomRecipientActivityResponse customResponse = new CustomRecipientActivityResponse(task.Result);
                            if (customResponse.Items.Any())
                            {
                                foreach (var customRecipientActivity in customResponse.Items)
                                {
                                    var contactInfo = recepientList.FirstOrDefault(x => x.Personal()?.FirstName == customRecipientActivity.FirstName
                                                        && x.Personal()?.LastName == customRecipientActivity.LastName
                                                        && x.Emails()?.PreferredEmail?.SmtpAddress == customRecipientActivity.Email);
                                    if (contactInfo != null)
                                    {
                                        customRecipientActivity.CustomCompany = contactInfo.GetCustom()?.Company;
                                        customRecipientActivity.CustomContactOwner = contactInfo.GetCustom()?.ContactOwner;
                                    }
                                }
                            }

                            args.HttpContext.Response.ContentType = "application/json; charset=utf-8";
                            args.HttpContext.Response.Output.WriteLine(JsonConvert.SerializeObject(customResponse));
                            args.HttpContext.Response.End();
                        }
                    }
                    catch (Exception ex)
                    {
                        throw ex;
                    }                    
                }
       }
}

public class CustomRecipientActivityResponse : RecipientActivityResponse
    {
        [JsonProperty("items")]
        public List<CustomRecipientActivity> Items { get; set; }
        public CustomRecipientActivityResponse(RecipientActivityResponse recipientActivityResponse)
        {
            if (recipientActivityResponse != null)
            {
                this.TotalCount = recipientActivityResponse.TotalCount;
                List<CustomRecipientActivity> customRecipientActivityList = new List<CustomRecipientActivity>();

                if (recipientActivityResponse.Data.Any())
                {
                    foreach (OpenClick item in recipientActivityResponse.Data)
                    {
                        customRecipientActivityList.Add(new CustomRecipientActivity(item));
                    }
                }

                Items = customRecipientActivityList;
            }
        }
    }

    public class CustomRecipientActivity : OpenClick
    {
        public CustomRecipientActivity(OpenClick recipientActivityModel)
        {
            if (recipientActivityModel != null)
            {
                this.FirstName = recipientActivityModel.FirstName;
                this.LastName = recipientActivityModel.LastName;
                this.Recency = recipientActivityModel.Recency;
                this.Email = recipientActivityModel.Email;
                this.Date = recipientActivityModel.Date;
                this.DateFormatted = recipientActivityModel.DateFormatted;
                this.Name = recipientActivityModel.Name;
                this.Url = recipientActivityModel.Url;
            }
        }

        [JsonProperty("custom_company")]
        public string CustomCompany { get; set; }

        [JsonProperty("custom_contactowner")]
        public string CustomContactOwner { get; set; }
    }
```