# Extend /sitecore/api/ssc/EXM/Message with additional data

Tags: exm, dependency-injection

I want to extend /sitecore/api/ssc/EXM/Message endpoint with additional data.

I added a new class

```
namespace Exm.Extended
{
    [ServicesController("EXM.Message")]
    public class MessageController : Sitecore.EmailCampaign.Server.Controllers.Message.MessageController
    {
        //

        //private ParentController _parent;
        public MessageController(
            ItemUtilExt itemUtil,
            ILanguageRepository languageRepository,
            IMessageVariantsService messageVariantsService,
            ILogger logger,
            IExmCampaignService exmCampaignService)

            : base(itemUtil, languageRepository, messageVariantsService, logger, exmCampaignService)
        {
           
        }

       
        [ActionName("DefaultAction")]
        public new Response Message( MessageContext data )
        {
            MessageResponse response = (MessageResponse) base.Message(data);
           //todo change/extend response
            return response;
        }
    }
}
```

I added a custom DI configurator

```
<configuration xmlns:patch="http://www.sitecore.net/xmlconfig/">
  <sitecore>
    <services>
      <configurator type="EXM.Custom.Configurator, My.Website"/>
...
```

and Replaced the default EXM MessageController with my custom one

```
 public void Configure(IServiceCollection serviceCollection)
 {
container.Replace(ServiceDescriptor.Transient(typeof(Sitecore.EmailCampaign.Server.Controllers.Message.MessageController), typeof(Exm.Extended.MessageController)));
..
```

if I debug now, the custom.messagehandler constructor is hit, but the new default action does never run => still always the Sitecore.EmailCampaign.Server.Controllers.Message.MessageController.Message action.

Comment: I am fairly confident that you can't actually do what you are thinking you are trying to do.  Question: What are you trying to achieve?

Comment: I have renamed the Controller to CustomMessageController and rewritten the API-Controller-Url in Speak-UI call in JS => but with Sitecore 9.3 that will not work anymore - because of the removed Speak UI in EXM.

Comment: Yeah, that's why I'm asking what you are trying to actually accomplish by doing this. If I understood the use case, there's probably another way to achieve it.

Answer (score -1):

You can take a look at my answer of my question at [Is there any way to update the response of a controller action by pipeline process?](https://sitecore.stackexchange.com/questions/25668/is-there-any-way-to-update-the-response-of-a-controller-action-by-pipeline-proce/25852#25852)

It's taken my couple of days to find out this way

Hope it can help